# Session data not cleared upon log out

Tags: php, session

I have problems with the log out system on my PHP page. When I try to log a second out, after logging out the first one, it displays me session details of the first accout.

So the problem is the following: I've created a registration + log in/ log out system for a site. The site is connected to a data base from phpmyadmin. 
I created 4 accounts. They are all ok in the data base.
When I logg in the first account everything is ok. After this I log out and try to log in with a new account. The log in is displayed as succseful but the session name and all other details are displayed with the first user's account.

here is my login:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="rlform-input" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="rlform-password" placeholder="Password" required>
   <input type="submit" class="rlform-btn" name="signIn" value="Login">
</form>
```

here is the logout:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php"); 

?>
```

I also tried the next log out code with no results:

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION = array(); 
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) { 
        $params = session_get_cookie_params(); 
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] ); 
    } 
    // Finally, destroy the session. 
    session_destroy(); 
    header("Location: index.php"); 
?>
```

login code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['login_id'])){
    if (isset($_SESSION['pageStore'])) {
        $pageStore = $_SESSION['pageStore'];
        header("location: $pageStore"); 
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['signIn'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        echo "Username & Password should not be empty";
    }
    else
    {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        include('config.php');
        $sQuery = "SELECT id, password from account where email=? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $hash);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->fetch()) { 
            if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
                $_SESSION['login_id'] = $id;
                if (isset($_SESSION['pageStore'])) {
                    $pageStore = $_SESSION['pageStore'];
                }
                else {
                    $pageStore = "index.php";
                }
                header("location: $pageStore"); 
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
            }
            else {
                echo 'Invalid Username & Password';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid Username & Password';
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close(); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This code seems like it should work. If you're seeing old values after logging in, it seems like the login page isn't assigning them properly.

Comment: @Barmar am not sure what's wrong then. Here is the login page
https://www.codepile.net/pile/mpk1kRbN

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question to add it.

Comment: @Barmar alright, sorry I didn't know. I am new here. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar do you see anything wrong with the log in? I can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: You didn't post the login code, you just posted two versions of logout code.

Comment: It's there now.

Comment: When you try to login the second time, does it verify the password properly? Do you get an error if you give an incorrect password?

Comment: When I try to login the second time if I introduce the correct logins of my second account it logs it successfully. If I try to log the second account with an incorrect password I get displayed this message: Invalid Username & Password.

Comment: Then I don't see how it can possibly be keeping you logged in with the previous ID. After it verifies the password it does `$_SESSION['login_id'] = $id;`.

Comment: Are you talking about other session variables? What do you see if you just put `var_dump($_SESSION);` right after `session_start();` in `login.php`?

Comment: @B.Fleming Hey! I tried your suggestion and sadly it wasn't a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any comments from B.Fleming. They've apparently realized that their suggestion was wrong and deleted it.

Comment: @Barmar adding var_dump got me the following message: array(1) { ["pageStore"]=> string(9) "index.php" }

Comment: I'm stumped. You assigned `$_SESSION = array();` when logging out, I don't see how it can still have a `pageStore` variable in it.

Comment: And it doesn't have `login_id`, so that IS being removed successfully. I can't explain why one variable is removed but the other isn't.

Comment: Yeah I did so in order to clean in... I got no idea either and it's my first PHP project.